# How to save/export gradients and textured effects in .png while minimizing file size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, cs5

I have been making a 2d game art for iphone in illustrator CS5, and buttons and background elements which use gradients and some textured effects are saved in `.png`.

I noticed using these effects dramatically increase the file size. Is there any way to reduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes - try using the save for web option

you can then choose to use a png-8 or png 24

png24s are larger but give much better results when using alpha/opactity on an image

if the image is solid or what the image is being placed on is going to be solid then a png 8 is better as you have a finer degree of control over the quality & ultimatly the size of the file - have a play around i recommend using the 2 screen option so you can see the orignal image and compair it to the one you optimize

bit more info here http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/saving-images-for-the-web/

Comment: Thanks for the link it helped explain things but the only problem I still keep having is the gradients look choppy. I mean its not glaringly obvious I don't if it stands out to me more because i'm looking for it but is there a way to reduce this choppy effects on the gradients (in particular)?? Again thanks for the advice.

Comment: have you tried adjusting the dither option when exporting the image - putting this too 100% should make the gradients cleaner